# react : apply hover to all elements inside parent div

Tags: reactjs, hover

I am struggling to apply the hover effect on parent and all child inside that parent div. I am trying following but its not working..

```
   function changeBackground(e) {
     e.target.style.backgroundColor = "#ff6f00";
     e.target.style.color = "#ffffff";   
      }
   function resetBackground(e){
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
   e.target.style.color = "#616161";
    }
    class InfoBlogs extends React.Component{
      render(){
       return(
         <div id = "parent" style = { styles.parentCard } onMouseOver={changeBackground} 
          onMouseLeave={resetBackground}>
             <div style={ styles.child1Card } id = "head">
             <div style = { styles.c11 }>
                 <h2 style={styles.cardTitle}>Challenge</h2>
             </div>
             <div style = { styles.c12 } id = "footer">
                 <IoIosLogIn style={ styles.iconStyle } />
             </div>
             </div>
             <div style={ styles.child2Card }>
                <p style={ styles.cardContent }>  The sky is pink.</p>
             </div>    
           </div>
           );
        }
      }
```

when mouse is hover on child it affetcs on that particular portion of child not on whole parent div.
can anyone tell me how can I achieve this using reactjs

Comment: I suggest, Do not use inline styling. Create an external css file use property :hover and apply your styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is `e.target` it is not always the element which is bound to that event. In this case you have to use `currentTarget`, it is always the element which is bound to the event even if event is on child element.

Change to this:

```
function changeBackground(e) {
     e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "#ff6f00";
     e.currentTarget.style.color = "#ffffff";   
}
function resetBackground(e){
    e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
    e.currentTarget.style.color = "#616161";
}
```

and i would suggest you to put the functions as a method to the class check below:

```js
class InfoBlogs extends React.Component{
      constructor(props){
         super(props);
         this.changeBackground = this.changeBackground.bind(this);
         this.resetBackground = this.resetBackground.bind(this);
      }
      changeBackground(e) {
        e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "#ff6f00";
        e.currentTarget.style.color = "#ffffff";   
      }
      resetBackground(e){
        e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
        e.currentTarget.style.color = "#616161";
      }
      render(){
       return(
          <div id="parent" style={ styles.parentCard } 
               onMouseOver={this.changeBackground} 
               onMouseLeave={this.resetBackground}>
             ...   
           </div>);
    }
}
```

---

#### Or you could use `React.createRef()` for better usage:

```js
class InfoBlogs extends React.Component{
      constructor(props){
         super(props);
         this.parentRef = React.createRef();
         this.changeBackground = this.changeBackground.bind(this);
         this.resetBackground = this.resetBackground.bind(this);
      }
      changeBackground(e) {
        this.parentRef.current.style.backgroundColor = "#ff6f00";
        this.parentRef.current.style.color = "#ffffff";   
      }
      resetBackground(e){
        this.parentRef.current.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
        this.parentRef.current.style.color = "#616161";
      }
      render(){
       return(
          <div id="parent" ref={this.parentRef} style={ styles.parentCard } 
               onMouseOver={this.changeBackground} 
               onMouseLeave={this.resetBackground}>
             ...   
           </div>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use the * and > selector in css

`.container:hover > * { /* your hover styles */ }`

If you hover the container (parent) then all first level child elements inside will get the applied stylings.